Godot - Apply a decal to a GridMap on a layer other than 1
In Godot, I have a GridMap that I'm applying decals to. Having added decal nodes, I was able to get them to apply as desired, except that they also affect other things I'd like to prevent them from affecting.
To keep them separate, I'd prefer to set the decal Cull Mask to something like layer 20, and the GridMap to the same.
Adjusting the decal's Cull Mask was no trouble.
But now, how do I change the render layers for the GridMap?..seeing that GridMap's have no 'layers' since they do not extend VisualInstance3D.
I'd be fine doing it manually or with code.

I've tried several things already though:

In code,

for id in gridmap.mesh_library.get_item_list():
    var mesh = gridmap.mesh_library.get_item_mesh(id)
    mesh.layers |= 1 << 20 # error: layers property does not exist
    # mesh is an ArrayMesh, not a MeshInstance3D


Manually:

To create the MeshLibrary, I have a Blender-exported gltf file. In Godot, if I right-click it and choose "New Inherited Scene", I can use "Scene > Export As > MeshLibrary" to make the library.
Just before that, however, I tried selecting each mesh and adjusting the "Layers" section that appears in the inherited scene, including layer 20. (See pic below)
This also has no effect, I presume because the export step throws this information away when converting the MeshInstance3Ds to ArrayMeshs (which can be seen by opening the mesh library .tres in a text editor).

